# strange socket timeout on Azure App Services, but works fine locally

Tags: php, sockets, azure

I'm having weird issues with sockets. I'm trying to connect to this IP with the port 25565 to figure out the ping of this particular IP/Server. I have a piece of code that works just fine locally and shows me the ping without fail, it also works just fine on an OVH Kimsufi box running nginx/PHP CGI. Yet on Microsoft Azure it does not, showing me the 10060 (timeout) errorcode and this message: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`. And only for this one IP. Another IP (`37.59.51.122`) works just fine. I have this app running in 3 different regions, EU West, US West and US East. It works in none of them.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function ping($host, $port)
{
    $time_start = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $fp = fsockopen("tcp://" . $host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if ($fp) {
        $time_end = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        fclose($fp);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        return $time;
    } else {
        return $errno . ":" . $errstr;
    }
}

echo ping("149.56.81.67", 25565);
```

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be causing this problem? Is there an azure-specific setting I need to change to fix this? 
Or is there an easy way to debug this on Azure? 
I'm quite new to Azure so I'm very unfamiliar with it.

EDIT: I have tried in many different regions (from japan to west US.) and couldn't find any settings about firewalls or IP blacklists. I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the problem. I had this script running in a loop, pinging it 5 times in quick succession. I have since added a 500ms delay between requests and I no longer have timeouts.

I wouldn't have figured this out without the help of evilSnobu. I figured out that tcpping.exe did work more often than my php script, despite the raw connection being virtually the same. The only difference was the delay between the requests. It was OVH's ddos protection firewall blocking my connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your last line to ping 8.8.8.8 on port 53 (Google's Public DNS Servers), it does work as expected as you already pointed out.

However, from Kudu's DebugConsole (*[https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole](https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole)*), if i do a `tcpping host:port` i see either your remote firewall acting up or packet loss.

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>tcpping 149.56.81.67:25565

Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
Connected to 149.56.81.67:25565, time taken: 78ms
Connected to 149.56.81.67:25565, time taken: 86ms
Complete: 2/4 successfull attempts (50%). Average success time: 82ms
```

This is why you see the timeout.

Try to run `tcpdump` on your remote server to see if it's really packet loss or the machine is simply not sending a SYN back (may send a RST instead).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find out the problem thanks to you telling me about the DebugConsole.